# Calculating the number of rounds and dice in a game where dice are added every time a certain number is rolled

Tags: probability, dice

I have $n$ dice with $s$ sides. With these, I play the following game:

1. Roll the unfrozen dice. All initial dice are unfrozen.
2. Freeze every die with a value below $s$
3. For every unfrozen die (i.e. each die with a value of $s$), add a new die to the game
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until all the dice are frozen.

How many rounds must be played before the game is over?

How many dice will there be at the end of the game?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Have you done any work on this yourself yet? If so what was your working?

Comment: Also, just to make sure I understand the problem correctly: if you're using standard 6-sided dice, you'd be freezing every die that didn't land on a 6, right?

Comment: Honestly, I'm a bit unsure where to start. I know I can calculate the probability of a single round being the last via $(1-\frac{1}{s})^n$ but beyond that I'm lost. I was planning on running some simulations today but I thought that maybe someone had some better mathematical knowledge.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex - yes, that is correct.

Comment: "How many rounds must be played before the game is over?" This is obviously random. YOu want the mean value, the distribution, or what ?

Comment: @leonbloy yes, those would be nice 

Comment: Then I'll give you "what". Only one round MUST be played before the game ends. Many more rounds are likely to be played, but only one has to be.

Comment: If you want the expected number of rounds, call that $R_n$, where $n$ is the number of dice in play. Note that if you play a round, there is an $\left(\frac {s-1}s\right)^n$ chance of having no dice in play, an $\binom n1\frac {(s-1)^{n-1}}{s^n}$ of having 1 die in play, an $\binom n2\frac {(s-1)^{n-2}}{s^n}$ chance of have 2 dice in play, etc. So $$R_n = 1 +\binom n1\frac {(s-1)^{n-1}}{s^n}R_2 + \binom n2\frac {(s-1)^{n-2}}{s^n}R_4 + ... + \binom nn\frac {(s-1)^0}{s^n}R_{2n}$$ Which gives you a recursive formula to find $R_{2n}$.